# Regular expression to find all “src” attribute of HTML “img” element only folder in PHP

Tags: php, html, regex, html-parsing, preg-match-all

I have a string, inside of that I have an image:

```
"<img src="img/programacao/51.jpg" style="width:200px;" /><p>balbalba</p><img src="img/programacao/46.jpg" style="width:200px;" /><p>balbalba</p><img src="/img/finalCinerio.jpg"><p>balbalba</p><img src="img/topo.jpg" />"
```

I just need the folder of images :img/programacao/

But my regex not working:

```
preg_match_all('/<img.*?src="([^"]*)"[^>]*>(?:<img>)?/', $text, $image);
```

Output

```
...
        [0] => img/topo.jpg
        [1] => img/p_veneza.png
        [2] => img/programacao/51.jpg
        [3] => img/programacao/46.jpg
        [4] => img/p_rio.png
        [5] => /img/finalCinerio.jpg
        [6] => img/rodape.jpg
```

...

But only need it

```
...
        [0] => img/programacao/51.jpg
        [1] => img/programacao/46.jpg
```

...

Comment: Then just `preg_grep()` the result list for the desired subset. (Else add a lookahead for "your" original regex.)

Comment: Why don't you just use a html parser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy beasy

```
 '/src=\"(?P<src>img\/programacao\/[^\"]+)\"/'
```

You don't really need the `img` tag unless you have a lot of `iframes` or `style/script` tags.  You can add it in but it makes reliably matching much, much harder.  The reason is there is no guarantee where the `src` attribute will show.

[Regx101](https://regex101.com/r/yE2uC6/3)

Most of this is pretty simple, literal matches

- `[^\"]+` = Not a quote ( match more then one ) matches any sequence that is not a quote.  I prefer this then the `.*?` match anything un-greedy for readability mostly
- `?P<src>` named `( ... )` capture group, return matches with a string key of `src`

I love named capture groups, although not as useful here with a single match.  However, it's main purpose is readability and it allows you to change your code latter. Such as adding another capture group and not worry about the match number changing on you, for example.

If you want to get really fancy

```
\<img.*?(?<!src=)src=(?P<quote>\"|\')(?P<src>img\/programacao\/[^\k<quote>]+)\k<quote>
```

- `(?<!src=)` negative look behind match anything `.*?` (non-greedy) if not `src=`
- `\k<quote>` back reference to the quote capture group, basically means the quote style `'` vs `"` must match

Although to be honest it's probably overkill.

[fancy demo](https://regex101.com/r/yE2uC6/4)

You could also use `preg_match_all` for this, but it depends how you read the file.  If you are reading it line for line then use preg_match.

Comment: OP only wants the image if it's in `img/programacao/`

Comment: @iismathwizard  Yes, there is that minor detail, but I used a named capture group so it's all good.

Comment: @iismathwizard You know, you could all rather add an explanation than substituting it with a regex demo link.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a parser and a simple regex to check the attribute starts with required directory...

```
$string = '<img src="img/programacao/51.jpg" style="width:200px;" /><p>balbalba</p><img src="img/programacao/46.jpg" style="width:200px;" /><p>balbalba</p><img src="/img/finalCinerio.jpg"><p>balbalba</p><img src="img/topo.jpg" />';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($string);
$images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
    if(preg_match('~^img/programacao/~', $image->getAttribute('src'))) {
        echo $image->getAttribute('src') . "\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
img/programacao/51.jpg
img/programacao/46.jpg
```

Comment: I highly agree with familiarizing yourself with a proper DOM manipulation tool such as that shown in the example.