# preg_replace src img from text

Tags: php, regex, src

I'm looking for a way to change all my src of img from a text.

Example :

```
$var = "Some text Some text Some text <img src=\"test1.jpg\"/> Some text Some text Some text Some text <img src=\"test2.jpg\"/>";
```

I would like to change the two src for a value in a array :

```
$array = array("apple.jpg", "banana.jpg");
```

Then $var should look like :

```
"Some text Some text Some text <img src=\"apple.jpg\"/> Some text Some text Some text Some text <img src=\"banana.jpg\"/>"
```

I was doing a loop of every preg_match with src of img but i don't know how can i modify the src in the final var.

(Sorry for my english :( )

Thank.

**EDIT :**

Thank you very much for your answer

How can i do if then, i would to modify only src which begin by "data like : src="data etc

Comment: Have you done some research or attempts of your own on creating `data:` URLs, or is this just repurposing the question to get more code suggestions?

Comment: I'd use a parser something like this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32020171/regular-expression-to-find-all-src-attribute-of-html-img-element-only-folder/32020330#32020330. But with http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way to do it:

```
$var = "Some text Some text Some text <img src=\"test1.jpg\"/> Some text Some text Some text Some text <img src=\"test2.jpg\"/>";
$array = array("apple.jpg", "banana.jpg");

$var = preg_replace_callback('#<img.+?src="([^"]*)".*?/?>#i', function($m) use (&$array) {
    return str_replace($m[1], array_shift($array), $m[0]);
}, $var);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do something like this:

```
$var = "Some text Some text Some text <img src=\"test1.jpg\"/> Some text Some text Some text Some text <img src=\"test2.jpg\"/>";
$replacements = array("apple.jpg", "banana.jpg");
$search_pattern = '/(?<=src=").*?(?=")/';
preg_match_all($search_pattern, $var, $matches);
$var = str_replace($matches[0], $replacements, $var);
```